# Do orthogonal polar factors of commuting matrices commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be two invertible commuting matrices (over the reals).

Given $A \in GL_n$, we denote by $O(A)$ its *orthogonal polar factor*, i.e the unique orthogonal matrix such that there exists a decomposition of $A$:

$$ A=O(A) \cdot P,$$ where $O(A) \in O_n, P $ is symmetric positive-definite.

Thus $O(A)=A(\sqrt{A^TA})^{-1}$.

Is it true that $O(A),O(B)$ commute?

---

I know that $O(A^{-1})=(O(A))^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false even for $n=2$. To see that, it suffices to randomly choose $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and after, $B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $AB=BA$ and $\det(A)\det(B)<0$.

An instance is: $A=\begin{pmatrix}27&-76\\-93&-72\end{pmatrix},B=A^2-A+2I$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate  on why $\det(A)\det(B) <0$ implies the orthogonal factors do not commute?

Comment: If $u\in O^+(2)\setminus\{\pm I\}$  and $v\in O^-(2)$ then $uv\not= vu$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is this fact you mentioned about non-commutativity of matrices in $O^+,O^-$ holds in higher dimensions than $2$?

Comment: $O^+(2)$ is commutative; yet, if $n\geq 3$, then $O^+(n)$ is not and the condition $\det(A)\det(B)<0$ is useless.